# How can i connect a iphone to another iphone or ipad programically using WiFi?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, communication, wifi

I am a newbie in iphone development and obj-c.How can i connect a iphone to another iphone or ipad programically using WiFi connection?can i able to transfer files between one iphone to another iphone or ipad using WiFi?I would really appreciate if someone could assist me in the correct way to do this, and if possible any sample code to get my started.
Thank You In Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can transfer data between two devices using wifi. Use CFNetwork framework. either you use bonjour service or an I.P. address to transfer data.. here is the guide for [CFNeworks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132)

Comment: you are welcomed.... but this [tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/) is helpful and the source code is [here](http://www.mobileorchard.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/chatty.zip)

Comment: i created a voice recognition project.it will create a text and the curresponding picture according to our voice.so i need to send the picture with the text from one iphone to another iphone or ipad..can u help me to do?]

Comment: so i am planning to create a button to sent above mentioned things to another iphone..what  code that i need to write in button click..

Comment: i am a newbie in iphone development.so can u please help me?

Comment: got one prblm that Base SDK is missing

Comment: It all right.... there is a delegate method i din't remember that. That converts you data into packets. That method is useful for you. But are you sending data to a device on local wi-fi or to a remote device??

Comment: `- (void)sendNetworkPacket:(NSDictionary*)packet;` and `- (void) receivedNetworkPacket:(NSDictionary*)message viaConnection:(Connection*)connection;`
 methods are important.

Comment: also one question..
 

 i created a application to get images from iPhone photo Folder using ALAssetLibrary. Can i retrieve image files using AlAssetLibrary without using Location Service? How can i avoid Location service in AlAssetLibrary?

Comment: or Can you help me to hide the Location Service Popup Window at the time of Application Start in iphone and ipad.It will show only once for an application at the time of first deployment.i think it is the reason of "ALAssetLibrary" which i used for retrieving images from Photo library.

Comment: Why are you using ALAssetLibrary use UIMediaPickerController instead... here is the [tutorial](http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=339).. if you are force to use that library, the pop up usually come because of `[locationManager startUpdating]` call.. Comment this calling and it will work.. and for new query please make new question or you can drop me email.

Comment: i searched "[location Manager startUpdating]"in my project.but i didn't get it.i think it is in ALAssetLibrary?

Comment: do you have the source code for this library???
If yes just find in the whole project `startUpdatingLocation` or `CLLocationManager`

Comment: no.i added this frame work using(rigtclik on->framework-.Add->existing framework).i got the frame work from there.the source folde  contains only 5 files with some Headers(ALAsset.h,ALrepresentation.h,AlAssetFilter.h,ALAssetLibrary.h,AssetLibrary.h)

Comment: why don't u use UIImagePicker

Comment: pop up  that asks "if u need to enable Location service".if i click NO then there is mo problms.else it will search for a location service.Application will break if Location service is not available. it will ask only one time...

Comment: Use UIImagePicker if you are simple getting images from the library.. can't you use that??

Answer (score 1):

You can use bonjour. Tutorial [here](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/)

[Getting Started with Networking & Internet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Networking_iPhone/_index.html)